# JavaScript - Connect Leaflet polygon with "lines"

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I'm currently working on a project.

Roughly, it is about pulling data from a database and wanting to display it on a leaflet card.

The data is saved from a MySql database in an array using a loop.

The "geodata" are fetched from the database in a while loop.

I then go through the data in a for loop and so I can display every value from the database on the map.

Here is the script:

```
<script src = "<? php echo SITE_URL?> / lib / js / base_map.js"> </script>
<script type = "text / javascript">
const map = createMap ({
render_elem: 'routemap',
provider: 'OpenStreetMap.MapTiler',
fullscreenControl: true,
});

// Variable / array for storing all museum information
var geodata = [];
var dep_coord = [];

// DATABASE and co

geodaten.push ({
'depicao': '<? php echo $ row [NUMBER]; ?> ',
'latitude': '<? php echo $ row [NUMBER]; ?> ',
'longitude': '<? php echo $ row [NUMBER]; ?> ',
'altitude': '<? php echo $ row [NUMBER]; ?> ',
'phase': '<? php echo $ row [NUMBER]; ?> ',
'groudspeed': '<? php echo $ row [NUMBER]; ?> ',
'positiontime': '<? php echo $ row [NUMBER]; ?> ',
});
// *** End of JavaScript ***


var current;
<? php
?>


for (var i = 0; i <geodaten.length; i ++) {

var current = geodata [i];
var redIcon = new L.Icon ({
iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-red.png',
shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
iconSize: [15, 25],
iconAnchor: [12, 41],
popupAnchor: [1, -34],
shadowSize: [41, 41]
});

var yellowIcon = new L.Icon ({
iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-yellow.png',
shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
iconSize: [30, 45],
iconAnchor: [12, 41],
popupAnchor: [1, -34],
shadowSize: [41, 41]
});

var greenIcon = new L.Icon ({
iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png',
shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
iconSize: [30, 45],
iconAnchor: [12, 41],
popupAnchor: [1, -34],
shadowSize: [41, 41]
});

const depCoords = L.latLng (<? php echo $ lat_dep;?>, <? php echo $ lng_dep;?>);
selDepMarker = L.marker (depCoords, {icon: yellowIcon}). bindPopup ("<? php echo $ dep;?>"). addTo (map);


const arrCoords = L.latLng (<? php echo $ lat_arr;?>, <? php echo $ lng_arr;?>);

selDepMarker = L.marker (arrCoords, {icon: greenIcon}). bindPopup ("<? php echo $ arr;?>"). addTo (map);

var latlngs = [[current.latitude, current.longitude]];


var polygon = L.polygon (latlngs, {color: 'blue', weight: 9}). addTo (map);

polygon.bindPopup ("Date:" + current.positiontime + "<br> Altitude:" + current.altitude + "<br> Groundspeed:" + current.groudspeed + "<br> Phase:" + current.phase + " <br> <br> Lat: "+ current.latitude +" <br> Lng: "+ current.longitude);

map.setView ([current.latitude, current.longitude], 5);

}
</script>
```

The "problem" is, I want to have a line between the polygons, so I want to connect the polygons, but can't find a way to do this.

It currently looks like this on the map:
https://prnt.sc/1gq8uyl

Can someone help me?

P.S. I took out the database connection!